# Leetcode 1965 finding missing information

Tags: syntax, syntax-error

Anybody can help me out for leetcode 1965 finding missing information. the question is as below :

Input:
Employees table:
+-------------+----------+
| employee_id | name     |
+-------------+----------+
| 2           | Crew     |
| 4           | Haven    |
| 5           | Kristian |
+-------------+----------+
Salaries table:
+-------------+--------+
| employee_id | salary |
+-------------+--------+
| 5           | 76071  |
| 1           | 22517  |
| 4           | 63539  |
+-------------+--------+
Output:
+-------------+
| employee_id |
+-------------+
| 1           |
| 2           |
+-------------+
Explanation:
Employees 1, 2, 4, and 5 are working at this company.
The name of employee 1 is missing.
The salary of employee 2 is missing.

My solution is as below: I don't know what's the mistake.

```
select employee_id
from Employees
outer join salaries on Employees.Employee_id=salaries.Employee_id
where name is null or salary is null;
```

---

It mentioned I have an error for syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select 
  employee_id
from
  Employees
where
  employee_id not in (select employee_id from Salaries)
union

select
  employee_id
from
  Salaries
where
  employee_id not in (select employee_id from Employees)
order by employee_id;
```

or

```
(SELECT 
    Employees.employee_id 
FROM 
    Employees LEFT JOIN Salaries 
ON 
    Employees.employee_id = Salaries.employee_id 
WHERE 
    Salaries.employee_id IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT 
    Salaries.employee_id 
FROM 
    Salaries LEFT JOIN Employees 
ON 
    Employees.employee_id = Salaries.employee_id 
WHERE 
    Employees.employee_id IS NULL) 
ORDER BY 
    employee_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT employee_id
FROM
( SELECT employee_id FROM employee
UNION ALL 
SELECT employee_id FROM salaries
)emp
GROUP BY employee_id
HAVING COUNT(employee_id)=1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

select
case
when t1.employee_id is not null then t1.employee_id
else t2.employee_id end as employee_id
from employees t1
full outer join salaries t2 on t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
where name is null or salary is null
order by employee_id asc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest query is below:

```
SELECT      employee_id 
FROM        employees 
WHERE       employee_id 
  NOT IN(
    SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID 
    FROM    SALARIES
  )
UNION
SELECT      employee_id 
FROM        SALARIES 
WHERE       employee_id 
  NOT IN(
    SELECT  EMPLOYEE_ID 
    FROM    EMPLOYEES
  )
ORDER BY    EMPLOYEE_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

the performance of join is better than subquery

```html
SELECT ISNULL(e.employee_id, s.employee_id) AS employee_id 
FROM Employees as e
FULL OUTER JOIN salaries s ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
WHERE e.employee_id IS NULL OR s.employee_id IS NULL
ORDER BY employee_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT employee_id FROM 
(select employee_id from employees union select employee_id from salaries) t
  WHERE employee_id IN
(
  SELECT CONCAT(e.employee_id,s.employee_id) AS employee_id FROM Employees e 
   FULL JOIN Salaries s 
  ON e.employee_id=s.employee_id 
  WHERE e.name IS NULL OR s.salary IS NULL
)
 ORDER BY employee_id;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server solution

```
SELECT concat(e.employee_id, s.employee_id) AS employee_id
FROM Employees AS e
FULL JOIN Salaries AS s
ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
WHERE name IS NULL OR salary IS NULL
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```